# Flutter can not find file on release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, tracking

When using [package 1](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator_2) or [package 2](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) for tracking the user, It's working fine in debug mode, But when generate release mode APK and trying to test on device this error obtains.

> E/flutter (19926): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library '.../LocationCallbackHandler' not found.

This is all permission which i added in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

What is the meaning of this error? and How can I solve it?

Comment: did you add all permissions ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post with permissions.

Comment: did you follow this setup ? https://github.com/rekabhq/background_locator/wiki/Setup

Comment: Exactly i did, It's working very fine in debug mode, But this error occured if i make "flutter build apk"

Comment: try to use flutter build apk --release

Comment: I tried it now, but did not work